# Windows Phone 8 detect screen unlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My WP8 app is set to run underneath the lock screen because it needs to continue to run even while the screen is locked, but I want to be able to detect when the user unlocks their screen, how do I do this?

What methods, if any, are called when the phone is unlocked?

Answer (score 4):

The frame's `Unobscured` event will fire when the user unlocks (it will also fire `Obscured` when the phone is being locked).

However these events will also fire for a MessageBox, a Reminder and the like so you will get other false positive. However it should be possible to detect the scenario you are after pretty easily.

See [this MSDN link for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206951%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

There are two proper events on `PhoneApplicationFrame` class for lock/unlock:

[PhoneApplicationFrame.Unobscured Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[PhoneApplicationFrame.Obscured Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

There is a bit more description about that on MSDN: [How to simulate the lock screen for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206951%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Understandingtheeventsthatoccurwhenthephoneislockedorunlocked)

Comment: How do I go about using these events? Where should they go in my app?